# Disable shutdown key on my keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, shutdown

I just bought a new keyboard (Inca IWS-549).
The keyboard has a nice style and 18 multimedia keys.
But among them at the left, I have the shutdown key (just above the esc key). If I touch it, the system shut downs and it's super sensitive. I want to disable this key. How can I do this?

I tried using keytweak, but first I have to press that key to change it which is impossible since the system shutdowns whenever I try that.

Any idea?

I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Control Panel > Power Options > Advanced > When I Press the Power Button on My Computer

[image]

Choose “Ask me what to do” and now when that button is pressed, you get the computer shutdown options.

Comment: Was that that simple? Thank you very much:) i thought those options only works for physical buttons on the tower. I had no option such as "ask me what to do" so i chose "do nothing" which is better for me.

Comment: Glad to help, Dude :)

Comment: Works on the actual power button on the laptop but not for the media key on my keyboard.

Comment: I don't think this is the appropriate answer. What the question asks is "power button on **keyborard**", not the "power button on **case**"

Comment: This works for both of them, that's the point:)