# Implement a Shutdown Confirmation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown

How do I configure Windows 10 so that it displays a confirmation dialog every time I press the `Shut down` button?

Sometimes I would shutdown my computer accidentally, as the sleep button is just above shutdown button, and lose my unsaved work:

[image]

Comment: Did you use google? there are tons of entries for your problem. I guess this should work, please try it: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-set-the-default-action-for-the-shutdown-dialog-in-windows-10/

Comment: @Jeremy how about the answer with 6 upvotes in this thread (even though it's windows 7?) http://superuser.com/questions/89957/how-to-force-a-confirm-shutdown-in-windows-7

Comment: @SimonS All I want is a simple confirmation dialog with yes/no buttons.

Comment: There's plenty of info out there on ways to do it.  IE: [Disable shutdown key on my keyboard?](http://superuser.com/questions/816088/disable-shutdown-key-on-my-keyboard), [Disabling Power button on keyboard](http://superuser.com/questions/55833/disabling-power-button-on-keyboard), [etc.](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com+disable+keyboard+power+button+windows)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Ah. What I actually mean is the buttons on screen. http://i.imgur.com/2Iph8RQ.png

Comment: @ths As you can see from the image in my post. I don't have problem selecting those buttons but, when I'm in a rush I may click the wrong button.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way to get a confirmation dialog upon hitting the shutdown button is to enable Shutdown Event Tracker:

[Configure Shutdown Event Tracker on the Local Computer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732119.aspx)

Since the link above is not up-to-date for Windows 10, the following are step-by-step instructions for Windows 10 (verified with version 21H1):

- Start `gpedit.msc`
- In the `Local Computer Policy` navigation pane, expand `Computer Configuration`, expand `Administrative Templates`, and click `All Settings`
- In the console pane, scroll down to the list of objects and double-click `Display Shutdown Event Tracker`
- Click `Enabled`
- Verify that in `Options`, `Shutdown Event Tracker should be displayed:` is set to `Always`
- Click `OK`

You will have to select a reason for the shutdown, like so:

[image]

Comment: This is same as SimonS' answer in comment. I don't want to choose a reason every time I shutdown my computer.

Comment: Well you can just click "Continue" without changing the default reason.

Comment: This is mainly a feature of the server versions of Windows which have it enabled by default. It generates entries in the event log which can be useful for system administrators.

Comment: This does exactly what you asked for: Confirmation on shutdown. You don't even have to select a reason from the reason box.

Comment: @xtian and others noticing the option isn't available: mine was semi-hidden. `gpedit.msc > Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > All Settings > Display Shutdown Event Tracker` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create the following batch file and use instead.

```
@ECHO OFF

:choice
set /P c=Are you sure you want to shutdown[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :yesplease
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :nothanks
goto :choice


:yesplease

shutdown /s /t 10
exit

:nothanks
exit
```

Paste this text into notepad, and save it as "shutdown.bat"  (include the quotations.) The quotes force it to save as a .bat file.

edit: removed unecessary pause statements

Comment: I'm not asking how to code the confirmation dialog. It'd be nice if the bat file can be ran when I click the shutdown button.

Answer (score 1):

A confirmation by itself can cause a problem, you might forget about it and leave the computer without it shutting down. The solution is like in Macs to have a confirmation but also auto-shutdown after some time if you don't cancel it.

I don't know of a way to do that natively on Windows, I think you need a 3rd party app for that. I know Penteract CMD GUI Creator can do it (See [here](https://penteract.net/site/Site1/Apps/Details/CMD_GUI/shutdown-options.aspx) and scroll to "Shutdown with confirmation and auto-execute"), but there might be other apps that do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because Windows 10 **Home** does not have **gpedit.msc**, you need to directly modify the registry to add `Shutdown Event Tracker` (even if gpedit.msc is forcibly added through cmd bat, the modification is useless).

Modify the registry method refer to https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78343-enable-disable-shutdown-event-tracker-windows-10-a.html

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Reliability]
> "ShutdownReasonOn"=dword:00000001
> "ShutdownReasonUI"=dword:00000001